# SQL returning null rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below PHP code for returning the user details from the table

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect'.mysqli_error());
    }
mysqli_select_db($con,"mysql");
$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$statement=mysqli_prepare($con,"Select * from bbau_login where username= ? and password= ? ");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$pasword);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$id,$name,$username,$password);

$user=array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement))
    {
        $user['name']=$name;
        $user['username']=$username;
        $user['password']=$password;
    }
echo json_encode($user);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

But it is returning null result when I am hitting this code from the application.
If I run the sql with hard coded value

```
Select * from bbau_login where username= 'aqsdfg' and password= 'adjbf'
```

then I am getting the desired result but not with the sql specified in the php script

Also I checked I am getting the proper values in $username and $password.
I think i need to pass the $username and $password in quotes. Please can someone help in writing correct query with quotes.

Comment: You are calling the prepared statement function so it cannot retrieve your data's

Answer (score 4):

Well, I would think that a consistent spelling of `pasword/password` would help immensely:

```
#  vv
$password=$_POST["password"];
:
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$pasword);
#                                                   ^
```

You may well, as you state, be "getting the proper values in `$username` and `$password`", but that's not going to help if you don't actually *use* what's in `$password` :-)

Comment: And test your $_POST variables too =)

Comment: @Fky, yes, there's all sorts of other good advice such as what you've stated, and explicitly asking for the columns in order (no `*` allowed) so that the result binding doesn't screw up should column order change, and doing the associative arrays correctly so that later rows don't overwrite earlier ones. But, really, the question is about why no rows are being returned, all that other stuff is superfluous in the context of the question :-)

Comment: Yes but an advice who can helps to improve code quality is good to learn ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have written incorrect spelling of password while passing it

change

```
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$pasword);
```

to

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$password);
```